# How to omit the rest if there are more than 3 of the same div block with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter

I want to collapse the rest of div if there are more than 3 with same class, and put show more/less link buttion instead. I am using a custom twitter app with php and json so if anyone have any ideas about how to do so, then please let me know.  My code only uses one div and auto populates

Code  below...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var displaylimit = 12;
var twitterprofile = "TWITTERUSERNAME";
var screenname = "SCREENNAME";
var showdirecttweets = true;
var showretweets = false;
var showtweetlinks = true;
var showprofilepic = true;
var showtweetactions = true;
var showretweetindicator = true;

var headerHTML = '';
var loadingHTML = '';
headerHTML += '<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter-bird-light.png" width="34" style="float:left;padding:3px 12px 0px 6px" alt="twitter bird" /></a>';
headerHTML += '<h1>'+screenname+' <span style="font-size:13px"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+twitterprofile+'" target="_blank">@'+twitterprofile+'</a></span></h1>';
loadingHTML += '<div id="loading-container"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="tweet loader" /></div>';

$('#twitter-feed').html(headerHTML + loadingHTML);

$.getJSON('http://www.XXXXXXX.com/_newSite/lib/twitter/tweets/tweets.php', 
    function(feeds) {   
       //alert(feeds);
        var feedHTML = '';
        var displayCounter = 1;         
        for (var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++) {
            var tweetscreenname = feeds[i].user.name;
            var tweetusername = feeds[i].user.screen_name;
            var profileimage = feeds[i].user.profile_image_url_https;
            var status = feeds[i].text; 
            var isaretweet = false;
            var isdirect = false;
            var tweetid = feeds[i].id_str;

            //If the tweet has been retweeted, get the profile pic of the tweeter
            if(typeof feeds[i].retweeted_status != 'undefined'){
               profileimage = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.profile_image_url_https;
               tweetscreenname = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.name;
               tweetusername = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.screen_name;
               tweetid = feeds[i].retweeted_status.id_str;
               status = feeds[i].retweeted_status.text; 
               isaretweet = true;
             };


             //Check to see if the tweet is a direct message
             if (feeds[i].text.substr(0,1) == "@") {
                 isdirect = true;
             }

            //console.log(feeds[i]);

             //Generate twitter feed HTML based on selected options
             if (((showretweets == true) || ((isaretweet == false) && (showretweets == false))) && ((showdirecttweets == true) || ((showdirecttweets == false) && (isdirect == false)))) { 
                if ((feeds[i].text.length > 1) && (displayCounter <= displaylimit)) {             
                    if (showtweetlinks == true) {
                        status = addlinks(status);
                    }

                    if (displayCounter == 1) {
                        feedHTML += headerHTML;
                    }

                    feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-article" id="tw'+displayCounter+'">';                                                       
                    feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-pic"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+profileimage+'"images/twitter-feed-icon.png" width="42" height="42" alt="twitter icon" /></a></div>';
                    feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-text"><p class="TwitterName"><span class="tweetprofilelink"><strong><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank">'+tweetscreenname+'</a></strong></p> <p></span><span class="tweet-time"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'/status/'+tweetid+'" target="_blank">'+relative_time(feeds[i].created_at)+'</a></span><br/>'+status+'</p>';

                    if ((isaretweet == true) && (showretweetindicator == true)) {
                        feedHTML += '<div id="retweet-indicator"></div>';
                    }                       
                    if (showtweetactions == true) {
                        feedHTML += '<div id="twitter-actions"><div class="intent" id="intent-reply"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+tweetid+'" title="Reply"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-retweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+tweetid+'" title="Retweet"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-fave"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+tweetid+'" title="Favourite"></a></div></div>';
                    }

                    feedHTML += '</div>';
                    feedHTML += '</div>';
                    displayCounter++;
                }   
             }
        }

        $('#twitter-feed').html(feedHTML);

        //Fix Twitter Spelling and change to true to reinstate animations Add twitter action animation and rollovers
        if (showtweetactions == flase) {                
            $('.titter-article').hover(function(){
                $(this).find('#titter-actions').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':0, 'margin-top':-20});
                $(this).find('#titter-actions').animate({'opacity':1, 'margin-top':0},200);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('#titter-actions').animate({'opacity':0, 'margin-top':-20},120, function(){
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                });
            });         

            //Add new window for action clicks

            $('#twitter-actions a').click(function(){
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
              window.open(url, 'tweet action window', 'width=580,height=500');
              return false;
            });
        }


}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var error = "";
         if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
           error = 'Connection problem. Check file path and www vs non-www in getJSON request';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            error = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            error = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            error = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            error = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            error = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            error = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }   
        alert("error: " + error);
});


//Function modified from Stack Overflow
function addlinks(data) {
    //Add link to all http:// links within tweets
     data = data.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
        return '<a href="'+url+'"  target="_blank">'+url+'</a>';
    });

    //Add link to @usernames used within tweets
    data = data.replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    //Add link to #hastags used within tweets
    data = data.replace(/\B#([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
        return '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q='+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    return data;
}


function relative_time(time_value) {
  var values = time_value.split(" ");
  time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
  var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
  var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
  var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
  var shortdate = time_value.substr(4,2) + " " + time_value.substr(0,3);
  delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

  if (delta < 60) {
    return '1m';
  } else if(delta < 120) {
    return '1m';
  } else if(delta < (60*60)) {
    return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + 'm';
  } else if(delta < (120*60)) {
    return '1h';
  } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
    return (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + 'h';
  } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
    //return '1 day';
    return shortdate;
  } else {
    return shortdate;
  }
}
```

});

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @MohammadReza I dont actually know where to start so i was looking to see a ruff idea of code... ?

Comment: Show us your source code, something that you're dealing with.

Comment: @Phil language for what the twitter app ? If so it is json it only uses one div <div class="twitter-feed"></div> and it auto populates

Comment: @MohammadReza CODE SUBMITTED

Comment: @MohammadReza does the code help any

Comment: you need to scale this code down to only the code that is relevant to the issue...there is no need for about 75% of this code to be posted

Comment: @charlietfl what will i remove ?

Comment: time code, error handlers etc.. anything that's not related

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.hidden { display:none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="class-container">
        <div class="twitter-feed">CONTENT 1</div>
        <div class="twitter-feed">CONTENT 2</div>
        <div class="twitter-feed">CONTENT 3</div>
        <div class="twitter-feed">CONTENT 4</div>
        <div class="twitter-feed">CONTENT 5</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With jQuery, after the page is loaded just before your closing body tag...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var addLink = false;
    $('.twitter-feed').each(function(index, element) {
        if (index > 2){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass("hidden");
            addLink = true;
        }
    });
    if(addLink){
        var sLink = "<br /><br /><a href='#' onclick='$(\".hidden\").toggle();'>Show More/Less</a>";
        $('body').append(sLink);
    }
 });
</script>
```

See JSFiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/satN7/)

Comment: this dosn't seem to work, the example i am trying to recreate is from sky.com their home page with the tweets expand and close

Comment: Works fine here, you need to run script after page loads using document.ready and look for the class name you need

Comment: could you implement it in my existing code if you dont mind ?

Comment: At the very end of your function on the .getJSON method add a call to a new function and create new function using javascript code in my answer above.  you will have to change the body selector in the append method if you want to put the show more/less link somewhere else.

Comment: Make sure you add the .hidden class to your CSS file too